# Rails 3: How do I route a controllers index and show actions to root while sending new/edit/destroy to /admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

First off, I'm using rails 3.0.8 with friendly_id 3.2.1.1.

I'd like to be able to view the posts at website.com/:title, so drop the "/posts".

But I'd also like to have an /admin view. From there, a user should be able to create/edit/destroy posts. I already have a admin.html.erb view with links to various actions.

Right now my routes file look like:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
  match "/:id" => "posts#show"
  match "/admin" => "posts#admin"
end
```

This works for website.com/:title, but for website.com/admin I get an error:

```
Couldn't find Post with ID=admin
```

.... which makes sense. But I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are run through top to bottom. So put your admin rule on top of the resource definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `/admin` first then it will work (as noted by cellcortex). You can also use `:constraints` if you can neatly separate your `:id` from `'admin'`; for example, if your `:id` values are numeric, then something like this should work:

```
match '/:id'   => 'posts#show', :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }
match '/admin' => 'posts#admin'
```

In a simple case like yours, putting things in the right order will work fine. However, if your routing is more complicated, then the `:constraints` approach might work better and avoid a some confusion and chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
resource :posts, :path => '/'
```

with this all of your article will be directly under root

So in Posts Class you may add this:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```